# ajax POST, trying to add the directory link adds the path twice

Tags: ajax, laravel, forms, post

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/bbr-category-configuration",
                data: "category_data",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
```

im testing out my ajax form in a console.log

[image: 1]

it says 404 not found but I thought alright sure, I missed the full path so I added:

```
url: "clinical/bbr-category-configuration",
```

This time, the path goes through my `clinical` folder twice as seen in the next screenshot

[image: 2]

How is this happening? (the directory getting added twice)

Comment: try `/clinical/bbr-category-configuration` with also a `/` before the clinical

Comment: First url starts with a `/`, so it starts from the root/top of your site, second doesn't start with a `/` so it starts from the folder the script is running - which I assume is `clinical`, so `clinical` shows up twice. Either start your second one with a `/` or remove the leading `/` from the first one

Comment: i see, what a quick fix thanks

Comment: can you post your `web.php` route ? so we can guide you right path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are defining are absolute and relative path of the url.

In JS or html file, if you redirect/request to any url with the **/urlPath** then your redirect/request will be from the base url(http://example.com/urlPath) onwards.

You can see this behaviour with simple anchor element. Just put these in the html file and you will see the result

```
<a href="clinical/bbr-category-configuration">Redirects from the current path</a>

<a href="/clinical/bbr-category-configuration">Redirects from the base url path</a>
```

The above **clinical/bbr-category-configuration** will redirect/request from your current url. if you are on *https://example.com/url/url2* then you will go to *https://example.com/url/clinical/bbr-category-configuration*

So In your case you should use `/clinical/bbr-category-configuration` as mentioned by @Aless55